# Clip layer Style effects (drop shadow) to pixels on layer below

Tags: adobe-photoshop, layer-style

Is there a way to clip a layer style to the layer below it, just like you can clip an adjustment layer to the layer below it? thanks. Layer one has a bottle image (with alpha transparency, so it's just the bottle, no background) and layer two has the cap (also with alpha transparency). When I apply a drop shadow layer style to the cap layer (to simulate the cap attached to the bottle) it appears on the neck of the bottle image below it (this I want) but it also appears in the transparent area around the bottle image. I'd like the drop shadow effect to just appear on the neck of the bottle. I've tried setting the layer style to multiply as this should limit the effect to just where there are pixels to multiply (ie: the bottle image below it) but it still appears everywhere, even in the transparent pixels (this makes no sense as what is the drop shadow effect being multiplied with? anything multiplied with 0 (transparent) should be 0. Thanks